# REST api naming convention technical or functional identifier

Tags: rest, api, naming-conventions, identifier

I have a user in database with two unique identifiers, one is technical (id table primary key autoincrement) and other one is functional.

Example :

User id : 40

User functional id: U12345

Which identifier should I use in my rest api naming ?

api/v1/users/40 or api/v1/users/U12345

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For REST, it's best you make use of the primary key in these circumstances.

`api/v1/users/{ID}` is much better and makes SQL joins seamless.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your answer but I confused because it seems functional id is known by other systems so maybe the rest api is easier to use with functional id by other systems as they don't know technical id of our system.

Comment: If as you say functional ID is already in use by third-party systems and you intend to make use of the conventional technical ID for such routes, you might choose to update your codebase to accept **both** routes. Routes using the technical ID `.../user/{ID}` should be the default for future third-party systems, while routes using the legacy functional ID `.../user/{UID}` should redirect (after some checks) to the default route `.../users/{ID}`.

Comment: Thanks, so third party should save our technical id on their system?

Comment: Yes. That makes sense going forward. If some third-party already make use of the functional ID, reroute to the one with the technical ID.